# Android bitmap manipulation, memory allocation and garbage collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-bitmap

**Edit:**
The goal of asking this question is to determine if I understand memory allocation and garbage collection in Java, not whether or not there are better ways to show and rotate an image in Android.

I am writing an Activity that lets a user open an image file, rotate the image, crop the image, then save the resulting rotated / cropped image to disc.

While solving this problem I have been keeping a close eye on allocated memory and am wondering if the behavior I am seeing is a) Expected or b) Indicative of a programming error.

**The behavior**

1) An image is selected from a gallery. The image is decoded from a file using BitmapFactory and I create a bitmap variable which I then display in my ImageView. I notice that when I do this my allocation jumps by a certain amount. Let's say 1MB for discussion.

2) The user wants to rotate the image by 90 degrees. They hit a button and the following code is run to rotate the bitmap.

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90.0);
    this.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.mBitmap, 0, 0, this.mBitmap.getWidth(), this.mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

This code takes the existing bitmap variable and applies a rotation to it which I then display in the ImageView again. This functions just fine, but if I watch the memory allocation I can see that it jumps by another 1 MB. This makes sense to me because I had the original bitmap in memory, then I created a copy that was rotated by 90 degrees in memory so I have 2x the original bitmap size in memory.

I have noticed that on some devices the garbage collector seems to be pretty aggressive and will only very briefly allow this 2x memory allocation but will almost immediately cause a GC and bring the allocated memory down to just 1MB. However, on other devices I have noticed that the 2x memory allocation won't immediately cause a GC. On those devices if I do multiple rotations I might get 3x or 4x of allocated memory before a GC occurs.

My question is, is amount of allocation happening a problem if, when the GC runs, the allocation drops down to its original value? In other words, am I creating some sort of memory leak here or are things behaving as they should and when the system needs memory it performs a GC and everything returns to normal?

**Edit:**
The app I am writing is for SDK versions 15+ (4.x and up)

Comment: Are this "other devices" works with android 2.3 and lower? Because on  old devices, bitmap uses "unmanaged" memory and you need to call Bitmap.recycle to free it.

Comment: @VolodymyrBaydalka See my edit. This app will run on 4.0 and up.

Comment: so dont create another Bitmap,  just use setImageMatrix